# How can I insert number in Ionic tabs

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I would like to show some pending books in a tab. I want to show a number in ionic tab icon. It is possible?

Like this image.

[image: number in ionic tab]

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-dark tabs-background-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Fila" icon-off="ion-ios-people dark" icon-on="ion-ios-people" href="#/tab/queue">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-queue"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Comissões" icon-off="ion-social-usd-outline dark" icon-on="ion-social-usd-outline" href="#/tab/profit">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-profit"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Agenda" icon-off="ion-ios-calendar-outline dark" icon-on="ion-ios-calendar-outline" href="#/tab/book">
    <span><number here ??></span>
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-book"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Perfil" icon-off="ion-android-person dark" icon-on="ion-android-person" href="#/tab/profile">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Just use badge Attr.
Thanks

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTab/

Answer (score 1):

Make your container be `position:relative` then add `position:absolute` to the number container ( it could be a p, span, div tag, anything, doesn't matter).
Then you can change the `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` property for the number container to position it how you want it.

```css
ion-tab{
  
  position:relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }

ion-tab span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  }
```

```html
    <ion-tab>
        <span>10 </span>
    </ion-tab>
```

Make sure you add that span tag inside the ion-tab that you want the number to be in.

Comment: It doesnt work, where I put the container in Ionic Tabs ? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/

Comment: Instead of `.container`, use `ion-tabs`, and put a span within it with the number you want to display.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `ion-tab` not `ion-tabs` . I've uploaded my answer

Comment: The number that i want to put close to icon tab is not a new tab. ion-tab make a new icon tab. Ionic Framework use angularjs directives. I'm wondering it is not possible using standard tabs. :(